# Memory Usage in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What are the most memory consuming reasons in SQL SERVER 2005?

Comment: What do you mean by "reasons"? You can edit your quest to clarify.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question: Please edit your question what do you mean by reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SQL Rocks](http://sqlnerd.blogspot.com/) article [Memory Use in SQL Server](http://sqlnerd.blogspot.com/2006/07/memory-use-in-sql-server.html) will probably answer your question.

I think this is one of the important parts:

> SQL Server's caching behavior is the
>   reason for the substantial memory use.
>   This is by design and is not a bug,
>   memory leak nor incorrect
>   configuration. Every time
>   SQL Server needs to read a page from
>   disk it caches the page in memory so
>   that the slow disk operation will be
>   unnecessary should SQL Server need
>   that page again. Every time SQL Server
>   needs to read a page from disk it
>   caches the page in memory so that the
>   slow disk operation will be
>   unnecessary SQL Server should need
>   that page again.

SQL Server is just memory hungry. The more memory you give it, the more it will use. SQL Server should probably always be run on its own server if it is doing anything non-trivial. In other words, don't install SQL Server on your domain controller, file server or source control repository (unless your source control repository uses SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

[Buffer pool](http://blogs.msdn.com/boduff/archive/2008/03/31/sql-server-memory-architecture-myth-busting-and-how-sad-is-awe-32-bit.aspx) for mainly data, plans, locks

Can you add some background please?